# Why do I get Invalid Character ORA-00911 error message on Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table for marking attendance of a student. The table has three columns **Attended_days,** **Absent_days** and **Registered_email**. I need to display a pie chart at the dash which shows the number of days a student was present vs. the number of days the student was absent. When I add a **where** clause to the chart `reg_email = ':APP_USER'`, I get the following error:
`Region → Attendance → Source → Where Clause`
`ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query!`
`ORA-06550: line 6, column 6: ORA-01740: missing double quote in identifier`

I searched the web and tried various methods but none worked. Any suggestions or any better way to do this.

Comment: Not sure, but does :app_user need to be wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: Almost surely `:APP_USER` should **not** be in single-quotes. and indeed in *any* quotes. Try it that way.

Comment: That's not even "almost", @mathguy, it is for sure.

Comment: @Littlefoot - that is a statistical joke. "Almost surely" means "with probability 1". In computing everything is finite sets (even when we don't think of it that way), so "almost surely" is the same as "surely".

Comment: Aha, @mathguy. I'm not good at jokes, even worse with statistical ones, not to mention foreign *lenghuage* :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `reg_email = ':APP_USER'` rather `reg_email = :APP_USER`, if you surround :APP_USER with quotes it becomes a litteral not the APP_USER variable